# Ruby on rails: how can i add multiple css files in rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How can i add multiple css files in rails project ?

I do,

<%= stylesheet_link_tag :cssone %>

Now i need to add more css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :cssone, :csstwo, and so on... %>
```

Answer (score 10):

There are some method to achieve this. First of all, you can specify each manually :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "first.css" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "second.css" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "third.css" %>
```

Then, you can wrap those 3 lines in a single one :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "first.css", "second.css", "third.css" %>
```

Also, if you want to include all of your stylesheets in the dedicated rails folder (/public/stylesheets/), you can do :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
```

If you have subfolders in the dedicated folder, you have to include the `:recursive` option

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :all, :recursive => true %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `(assets/stylesheets)`
Add your multiple css file let us take eg-`a.css`,`b.css` and `c.css`

## NOW

In `application.rb` write

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "first.css", "second.css", "third.css" %>
```