# Ruby on rails: devise problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have this in views/posts/index.html.erb

```
    <% if user_signed_in? %>        
      <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => 'delete') %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %>
    <% end %>
```

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
....

class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
end

rake routes:

```
        new_user_session GET    /usuarios/login(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            user_session POST   /usuarios/login(.:format)                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    destroy_user_session DELETE /usuarios/logout(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_password POST   /usuarios/secret(.:format)                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       new_user_password GET    /usuarios/secret/new(.:format)              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      edit_user_password GET    /usuarios/secret/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         PUT    /usuarios/secret(.:format)                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /usuarios/register/cancel(.:format)         {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       user_registration POST   /usuarios/register(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /usuarios/register/cmon_let_me_in(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
  edit_user_registration GET    /usuarios/register/edit(.:format)           {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         PUT    /usuarios/register(.:format)                {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         DELETE /usuarios/register(.:format)                {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
                         POST   /posts(.:format)                            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
                                /posts/:id/categ(.:format)                  {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"categ"}
                                /posts/:id/tag_posts(.:format)              {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"tag_posts"}
     posts_searcharchive        /posts/searcharchive(.:format)              {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"searcharchive"}
              categories GET    /categories(.:format)                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"categories"}
                         POST   /categories(.:format)                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"categories"}
            new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"categories"}
           edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)              {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"categories"}
                category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories"}
                         PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"update", :controller=>"categories"}
                         DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"categories"}
                comments GET    /comments(.:format)                         {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
                         POST   /comments(.:format)                         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
             new_comment GET    /comments/new(.:format)                     {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
            edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)                {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
                 comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)                     {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
                         PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)                     {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
                         DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)                     {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
              countpages GET    /countpages(.:format)                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"countpages"}
                         POST   /countpages(.:format)                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"countpages"}
           new_countpage GET    /countpages/new(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"countpages"}
          edit_countpage GET    /countpages/:id/edit(.:format)              {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"countpages"}
               countpage GET    /countpages/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"show", :controller=>"countpages"}
                         PUT    /countpages/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"update", :controller=>"countpages"}
                         DELETE /countpages/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"countpages"}
                    root        /(.:format)                                 {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"index"}
```

in routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users, :path => "usuarios", :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret', :confirmation => 'verification', :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'register', :sign_up => 'cmon_let_me_in' }
```

I got error:

ActionController::RoutingError in Devise/sessions#new

Showing app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #16 raised:

No route matches {:controller=>"devise/posts"}

this is root:   root :to => "posts#index"  , when  i hit http://0.0.0.0:3000 , it redirects to http://0.0.0.0:3000/usuarios/login and got this error,

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__647429696_90155120__982654953'

Comment: The error comes from application.html.erb. Can you please post the contents of that file as well?

Comment: no problem with application.html.erb , http://pastebin.com/Nka2j54e

Comment: I don't know why 0% accept. I flaged answered if it's answered.

Comment: I think your pastebin link of your application.html.erb is really badly malformed. Also, looking through your asked questions you do actually correctly answered questions not accepted - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652196

Comment: You need to show us line 16 of application.html.erb

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you change the default route for user : `devise_for :users, :path => "usuarios",` I mean, now all your routes will be `_usuario_` i.e. :

```
<% if usuario_signed_in? %>        
      <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_usuario_session_path %>
    <% else %>.....
```

Comment: ah? No route matches {:controller=>"devise/posts"} , where in this code are you calling that? , I think is in other file that you have this error